# Why text attachment sent using Flask Mail is empty?

Tags: python, email, flask, flask-mail

I am attempting to send an email with Flask-Mail with a .txt file attachment. Thus far either I get an error or the email sends but the .txt. file is blank I've tried it two ways:

One way following the documentation:

```
with current_app.open_resource("sample.txt") as fp:
    msg.attach("sample.txt","text/plain", fp.read())
```

This leads to an Error:

```
TypeError: 'exceptions.IOError' object is not callable
```

I also tried it without the open_resource method:

```
 msg.attach("sample.txt","text/plain")
    mail.send(msg)
```

This led to the email sending but the .txt. attachment was blank.

Full try/except block below

```
try: 
    msg = Message("New File",
              sender="SENDER",
              recipients=["RECIPIENT"])
    msg.body = "Hello Flask message sent from Flask-Mail"
    with current_app.open_resource("sample.txt") as fp:
        msg.attach("sample.txt","text/plain", fp.read())
    mail.send(msg)
except Exception as e:
    return e
return "file was successfully sent"
```

What am I missing in order for the attachment to be properly sent?

Comment: Your code looks fine, I assume you have a problem with your mail server configuration or `sample.txt` file location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Flask-Mail documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/), this should perfectly do it:

```
with current_app.open_resource("sample.txt") as fp:
    msg.attach("sample.txt","text/plain", fp.read())
mail.send(msg)
```

- Where `current_app.open_resource("sample.txt")` opens file with `sample.txt` location to read
- And `msg.attach("sample.txt","text/plain", fp.read())` attaches it using `sample.txt` as attachment name
- Finally `mail.send(msg)` sends email

Make sure your `sample.txt` file location is correct and if it does not work, enable debugging by `app.config['DEBUG'] = True` and see what is the error.

Comment: i tried the same method its not working. question link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811429/text-attachment-sent-using-flask-mail-is-not-received